# Splitting a multi-word string into two variables

Tags: python

I have a document that holds login details as "username1, password1, username2, password2 etc." Is there a way of splitting them into two arrays that hold just usernames and just passwords?

I tried doing: `usernames, passwords = login.split(",")` but that's just a `ValueError`.

Sorry if it's something so obvious!

Update:

`login = "username1, password1, username2, password2"`

Comment: your input is not obvious to me. could you show the exact input file format?

Comment: Could you describe what exactly it is you're trying to achieve?

Comment: That will work fine, login is a string with a single comma in it.

Comment: I second @CharinduEdirisooriya's comment. This could certainly be done, but if you would explain your larger goal, we could probably help you accomplish it in a better way.

Answer (score 7):

you are getting `ValueError` because `login.split()` returns a list with more than two elements.
If your data are formatted as `username, password` you can split and then slice the list:

```
login = "username1, password1, username2, password2"
data = login.split(",")


usernames = data[::2]
passwords = data[1::2]
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution works on even and odd index of a list.  If even index, then append to usernames, if odd index then to passwords.

```
login='username1, password1, username2, password2'
usernames, passwords  = [], []
s = login.split(",")
for i in range(len(s)):
    usernames.append(s[i]) if i%2 == 0 else passwords.append(s[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe you have the file structure like below:

```
username1, password1, username2, password2 
username3, password3, username4, password4
username5, password5, username6, password6 
username7, password7, username8, password8
```

then the below code will work ,

[image]

```
import csv
list_username=[]
list_pwd=[]
with open("untitled.txt") as f1:
    csvrow=csv.reader(f1,delimiter=",")
    for row in csvrow:
     usernames = row[0] + "," +row[2]
     passwords = row[1] + "," +row[3]   
     list_username.append(usernames)   
     list_pwd.append(passwords)
print(list_username)
print(list_pwd)
```

i have attached the output of the code as well,

[image]